# Переменная в inlineNav jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        
        // id выбранной строки
        var lastSel=null;
        
        // Данные в выбранной строке.
        var selectedRowData = null;
        
        // Новые данные в выбранной строке
        var newRowData = null;
        
        
        
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
  //width:919, 
        height:'auto',
     altRows: true,
  autowidth: true,
        regional : "ru",           // Русская локалка
        forceRegional : true,
        url:'getdata.php?q=2',         // Данные берём с getdata.php
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        editurl: 'saverow.php',     // URL для сохранения изменений.
        
       
        
        
            colNames:["id", "Наименование материала", "Цена", "Код", "Служба", "Месяц", "Год", "Ед. изм.",  
  "Ост. кол. на начало", "Ост. сумм на начало","Получено (кол-во)","Получено (сумма)"],
            colModel :[{
                name:'id',
                index:'id',
                key : true, 
                width:20, 
                align:'left', 
                search:false
                }, {
                name: 'NAME', 
                index:"NAME", 
                width:150, 
                align:'left', 
                editable:false, 
                search:true, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, //{
//                name: "RASHOD", 
//                index:"RASHOD", 
//                width: 150, 
//                align: 'left', 
//                editoptions: {
//                    'custom_element' : autocomplete_element,
//                    'custom_value' : autocomplete_value
//                            }, 
//                editable:true, 
//                edittype:"custom", 
//                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
//                }, 
                {
                name: "PRICE", 
                index:"PRICE", 
                width:80, 
                align:'left',
                //hidden:true, //делает столбец скрытым 
                editable:true, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "COD", 
                index:"COD", 
                width:80, 
                align:'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "SKLAD",
                index:"SKLAD", 
                width:30, 
                align:'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "MONTH", 
                index:"MONTH", 
                width:20, 
                align:'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "YEAR", 
                index:"YEAR", 
                width:20, 
                align:'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "ED_IZM", 
                index:"ED_IZM", 
                width: 20, 
                align:'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "OS_N_K", 
                index:"OS_N_K", 
                width: 50, 
                align: 'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "OS_N_D", 
                index:"OS_N_D", 
                width: 50, 
                align: 'left', 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "OS_K_K", 
                index:"OS_K_K", 
                width: 50, 
                align: 'left', 
                editrules : { number : true, required : true }, 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }, {
                name: "OS_K_D", 
                index:"OS_K_D", 
                width: 50, 
                align: 'left', 
                editrules : { number : true, required : true }, 
                editable:false, 
                edittype:"text", 
                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
                }//,  {
//                name: "K_RAS", 
//                index:"K_RAS", 
//                width: 50, 
//                align: 'left', 
//                editrules : { number : true, required : true }, 
//                editable:true, 
//                edittype:"text", 
//                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
//                },  {
//                name: "S_RAS", 
//                index:"S_RAS", 
//                width: 50, 
//                align: 'left', 
//                editrules : { number : true, required : true }, 
//                editable:false, 
//                edittype:"text", 
//                searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
//                }
    ],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum:20,
            rowList:[20,40,60],
            sortname: 'id',
            sortorder: "asc",
            //multiselect: true,
   //excelexport:true,
            viewrecords: true,
            
            caption: "Ведомость движения и расхода материальных ценностей",
    


        onSelectRow: function (ids) {
        //создаем переменную куда получаем выбранные значения    
        var select_cod=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).COD;
        var select_price=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).PRICE;
        var select_oskn=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).OS_K_K;
        var select_oskp=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).OS_N_K;
        
      
        select_obk = (parseFloat(select_oskn)+parseFloat(select_oskp));
        
              
  if(ids == null) {
   ids=0;
   if(jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') >0 )
   {
    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"getdata_d.php?q=1&id="+ids+"&cod="+select_cod+"&price="+select_price+"&os_k_k="+select_oskn+"&os_n_k="+select_oskp+"&select_obk="+select_obk,page:1});
    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"Выбранный ID: "+ids).trigger('reloadGrid');
   }
  } else {
   jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"getdata_d.php?q=1&id="+ids+"&cod="+select_cod+"&price="+select_price+"&os_k_k="+select_oskn+"&os_n_k="+select_oskp+"&select_obk="+select_obk,page:1});
   jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"Выбранный ID: "+ids).trigger('reloadGrid');
            jQuery("#list").restoreRow(lastSel);
            
            
              
  }
 },   
                    
           
            
        }).navGrid('#pager',{view:true, del:false, add:false, edit:false, search:false}, // маленькая панель инструментов внизу таблици
   {}, //  default settings for edit
   {}, //  default settings for add
   {},  // delete instead that del:false we need this
   {closeOnEscape:true, multipleSearch:true, closeAfterSearch:true}, // search options
   {} /* view parameters*/
  );

  
       
 });

 </script>
 

 
 <script type="text/javascript">
   // id выбранной строки
        var lastSel=null;

      jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid({
        height:'auto',
  altRows: true,
  autowidth: true,
  url:'getdata_d.php?q=1&id=0',
  datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        editurl: 'saverow_d.php',     // URL для сохранения изменений. 
         
              
  colNames:['id', 'Код', 'Расход', 'Факт. (кол-во)', 'Факт. (сумма)'],
  colModel:[{
   name:'id',
            index:'id',
            editable:false, 
            width:55
            }, {
            name:'COD',
            index:'COD',
            editable:false, 
            width:80
            }, {
             name: "RASHOD", 
             index:"RASHOD", 
             width: 150, 
             align: 'left', 
             editoptions: {
                    'custom_element' : autocomplete_element,
                    'custom_value' : autocomplete_value
                    
                            }, 
             editable:true, 
             edittype:"custom", 
             searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
            }, {
            name:'KOL',
            index:'KOL',
            editrules : { number : true, required : true },
            editable:true, 
            width:80, 
            align:"left",
            edittype:"text",
            //summaryType:'sum', 
            searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','bw','cn']}
            }, {
            name:'SUM',
            index:'SUM',
            editable:false, 
            width:80, 
            align:"left"
            }   
   
  ],
  rowNum:20,
  rowList:[10,20,40],
  pager: $('#pager_d'),
  sortname: 'id',
  viewrecords: true,
  sortorder: "asc",
  //multiselect: true,
        footerrow : true,
     userDataOnFooter : true,
     caption:"Объём выполненых работ и изготовленных материальных ценностей",
        
        
        
      
         onSelectRow: function(id) {
                
                jQuery("#list_d").restoreRow(lastSel);
            },
            
   
            
               
            
              
        
 });
    
    
    
    jQuery("#list_d").navGrid('#pager_d',{add:false, edit:false, del:true, search:false},
            {}, //  default settings for edit
   {}, //  default settings for add
   { // опции для удаления
           // modal: true,
            url: "del.php",
            
            }, // delete instead that del:false we need this
            
   {}, // search options
   {} /* view parameters*/
    );
    
    



    
    
    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pager_d",
    
    { edit: true,
      editicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
      add: true,
      addicon:"ui-icon-plus",
      save: true,
      saveicon:"ui-icon-disk",
      cancel: true,
      cancelicon:"ui-icon-cancel",
      
      addParams : {
        rowID : "значение из базы",
        useFormatter : false,
        initdata : {id : "значение из базы", COD : "значение из базы", KOL : select_obk, SUM : "значение из базы"},
        position : "first",
        useDefValues : false,
        useFormatter : false,
        addRowParams : {keys : true, extraparam : {}}
      
      },
      editParams : {keys : true} }    
    
    );

    
    //добавляем кнопку выгрузка в Exel
      jQuery("#list_d").navButtonAdd('#pager_d',{
            caption:"Excel", buttonimg:"img/excel1.png", onClickButton: function(){ 
                document.location.href = "excel.php";
                }, 
                position:"last"
            });
$('#list_d_iladd').click(function(){
  alert('Вы нажали на элемент ' + select_obk);
});
   
</script>





















</body>

</html>
```

Доброе время суток пытаюсь вставить переменную select_obk в консоли выводится что она не определена, хотя alert выводит значение. В чем может быть дело или как правильно передать туда переменную, заранее спасибо

Comment: Все верно вам говорит консоль. В указанном коде нет объявления переменной `select_obk`.

Comment: onSelectRow: function (ids) {
        //создаем переменную куда получаем выбранные значения    
        var select_cod=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).COD;
        var select_price=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).PRICE;
        var select_oskn=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).OS_K_K;
        var select_oskp=$(this).jqGrid('getRowData', ids).OS_N_K;
        
      
        select_obk = (parseFloat(select_oskn)+parseFloat(select_oskp)); Перименную объявляю здесь. Извените сразу весь код не выложил